# Not specifying which list implementation

Tags: java, list, arraylist, dao

I have a doubt considering changing this :

```
List<String> elements = new ArrayList<String>();

 elements = elementDao.findElementsById(elementId);
```

to

```
List<String> elements;

elements = elementDao.findElementsById(elementId);
```

(I'm using DAO with Hibernate)

Can this cause any errors or exceptions (the fact that i'm not specifying which List implementation should be returned) ?

Comment: This _may_ cause a compiler warning.

Comment: @mre: What compiler warning do you mean?

Comment: @beny23, a type safety warning, but I really wasn't too confident about it, but thought it would be worth mentioning. If I'm wrong, I will remove my comment. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one creates a new arraylist for nothing. The created list is just garbage that has to be collected.

The second one is better, but should be reduced to

```
List<String> elements = elementDao.findElementsById(elementId);
```

You seem to be thinking that the assignment operator could be used to fill a list created by the caller. This is not the case. the assignment operator just takes the reference to the list created by the DAO (and which could be any kind of List), and assigns this reference to the variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can safely change it because:

```
List<String> elements = new ArrayList<String>();
```

creates a new `ArrayList` and assigns it to `elements`, then

```
elements = elementDao.findElementsById(elementId);
```

throws the original `ArrayList` away (and marks it to be garbage collected) and assign `elements` to it the `List` created inside `elementDao`, so the second approach is just as safe and more efficient.